# Safari Extension modify iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, safari-extension

So I gave up trying to defend my injected script's jQuery UI against all the CSS of the world. I decided to create an iframe.

When I click the toolbar button I have this code in the injected script to see if the iframe exists yet:

```
if($('#myiframe').length == 0) {
    $('body').append('<iframe src="' + safari.extension.baseURI + 'popup.html" id="myiframe" style="width: 400px; height: 500px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 100000;">');
    $('#content').append(strData);   
} else if($('#myiframe').is(':visible') == true) {
    $('#myiframe').hide();
} else {
    $('#myiframe').show();
}
```

If #myiframe doesn't exist I'll create it. I'm using popup.html as the src for my iframe. In popup.html I have a div with the id "content". My goal is to stuff strData, which is a bunch of HTML data, into #content with append. This is not working.

The iframe is drawn perfectly and opens and closes based on me clicking the button. But I am not able to append strData. I know it can be done but I don't know how. There is one example floating around here http://mg.to/test/dynaframe.html but when I tried this method the content underneath went completely blank. Help!

Comment: I looked at extensions the other day. Don't you need to register the events with the javascript API that safari outlines in their reference? Are you doing that?

Comment: Sam, not sure what you mean. The extension works 100% if I don't use iframes but the various sites' CSS will clobber my extension I am trying to avoid the mess and go iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You need your own namespace in your CSS. If your classnames match that of the page's, then you'll have some conflicts. Something like

```
.mynamespace_div_text
```

instead of `div_text`